# C# Use string as a resource name

Tags: c#

I'm creating a card game similar to [Play Your Cards Right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Play_Your_Cards_Right) using C# WFA.

I have 52 card faces as PNGs that I want to be able to apply to pictureboxes. I have 10 picture boxes, `pbP1Card1` -> `pbP1Card5` and `pbP2Card1` -> `pbP2Card5`. When a card is drawn, I want to change the next picturebox from a cardback image to the corresponding card face for the newly drawn card.

I am trying to find a fast solution to getting this to work across all ten PBs. I am thinking of a method similar to this:

```
string picbox = "pbP1Card1"; 
string card = "ace_of_spades";
```

is used in

```
picbox.Image = Properties.Resources.card
```

Where the picbox being targeted and the current card can be changed accordingly.

EDIT:
Along with Joe's answer, I have achieved what I wanted by using the following:

```
picbox.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(card)));
```

Comment: Navigate into what the auto-generated Resources file does -- it's fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string picbox = "pbP1Card1"; 
picbox.Image = Properties.Resources.card
```

That's not gonna work at all the way you want. Using string values as variable name references is not good practice. Instead, define your PictureBox controls with an array, like this:

```
PictureBox[,] cards = new PictureBox[1,4];
```

Now, `pbP1Card1` will be `cards[0,0]`. `pbP2Card5` would be `cards[1,4]`, and you can use integer variables to increment through the positions. So you might have a line of code somewhere that looks like this:

```
cards[0,i].Image = Properties.Resources.card
```

The best thing here is you don't have to remove and recreate your existing PictureBoxes. Instead, your initialization code has a few lines that look like this:

```
 cards[0,0] = pbP1Card1;
 cards[0,1] = pbP1Card2;
 cards[0,2] = pbP1Card3;
 //...
 cards[1,4] = pbP2Card4;
```

Since PictureBox is a reference type, you will be able to access the same PictureBox object using either reference, so anything you've already written to use the existing names will still work.

Comment: The array has worked brilliantly; thank you! I am wondering if you know how to implement using the string for the correct resource. For example, the variable *card* will be equal to the name of the selected card (ace_of_spades, _2_of_hearts,etc).

Comment: You don't. It's possible to do this via reflection, but reflection is slow, difficult, and probe to runtine errors.

Comment: A large switch statement to select the correct file, then?

Comment: Sure, but I'd use a `Dictionary<string,PictureBox>` before I tried a `switch`, and again: that's more code, it's not more readable, and it leaves you open to runtime errors because you have to be able to handle bad strings.

Comment: You can also do something like `this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().Where(pb => pb.Name == "pbP1Card1");`

Comment: How would I access the image property with your previous comment?

Comment: `foreach (var pb in this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().Where(pb => pb.Name == "pbP1Card1")) pb.Image = Properties.Resources.card;`

Comment: But again: use the arrays for this.